# Regex replace on specific column with SED/AWK

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I have data that looks like this (TAB delimited):

```
Organ K     ClustNo Analysis
LN    K200  C12     Gene Ontology
LN    K200  C116    Gene Ontology
CN    K200  C2      Gene Ontology
```

What I want to do is to remove `C` for every row on *3rd column*, except header row:

```
Organ K     ClustNo Analysis
LN    K200  12      Gene Ontology
LN    K200  116     Gene Ontology
CN    K200  2       Gene Ontology
```

This won't do because it will affect other columns and header row:

```
sed 's/C//'
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Using awk

`awk` is a good tool for this:

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NR>=2{sub(/^C/, "", $3)} 1' file
Organ   K       ClustNo Analysis
LN      K200    12      Gene Ontology
LN      K200    116     Gene Ontology
CN      K200    2       Gene Ontology
```

#### How it works

- `-F'\t'`

  Use tab as the field delimiter on input.
- `-v OFS='\t'`

  Use tab as the field delimiter on output
- `NR>=2 {sub(/^C/, "", $3)}`

  Remove the initial `C` from field 3 only for lines after the first line.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.

### Using sed

```
$ sed -r '2,$ s/(([^\t]+\t+){2})C/\1/' file
Organ   K       ClustNo Analysis
LN      K200    12      Gene Ontology
LN      K200    116     Gene Ontology
CN      K200    2       Gene Ontology
```

- `-r`

  Use extended regular expressions.  (On Mac OSX or other BSD platform, use `-E` instead.)
- `2,$ s/(([^\t]+\t){2})C/\1/`

  This substitution is applied only for lines from 2 to the end of the file.

  `(([^\t]+\t){2})` matches the first two tab-separated columns.  This assumes that only one tab separates each column.  Because the regex is enclosed in parens, what it matches will be available later as `\1`.

  `C` this match `C`.

  `\1` replaces the matched text with just the first two columns, not the `C`..

Comment: Thanks. We can't use `except first` cause other column after the 2nd may contain `C`. Actually there are more than just 4 columns.

Comment: And it's tab delimited. How can I modify your code?

Comment: Tab deliminated is important.  You should had said that up front.  I'll make some changes.