# How to convert in specific column in csv in shell script linux

Tags: linux, shell, sed

i have a file output.csv like this :

```
No | Timestamp | Table | agg | result | percentage | status | year | month | day
2022-09-30 00:00:00|2022-09-30 00:00:00|Source|count|287.472.321|-4.83%|Normal|2022|202209|20220930
2022-09-30 00:00:00|2022-09-30 00:00:00|Source|count|498.512.903|-4.05%|Normal|2022|202209|20220930
2022-09-30 00:00:00|2022-09-30 00:00:00|Source|count|19.089.222|-19.4%|Normal|2022|202209|20220930
2022-09-30 00:00:00|2022-09-30 00:00:00|Source|count|29.014.921|-2.47%|Normal|2022|202209|20220930
2022-09-30 00:00:00|2022-09-30 00:00:00|Source|count|148.770.415|-0.14%|Normal|2022|202209|20220930
```

all i wanna do is converting "." to blankspace in 5th column without affect on 6th column like this :

```
2022-09-30 00:00:00|2022-09-30 00:00:00|Source|count|287472321|-4.83%|Normal|2022|202209|20220930
2022-09-30 00:00:00|2022-09-30 00:00:00|Source|count|498512903|-4.05%|Normal|2022|202209|20220930
2022-09-30 00:00:00|2022-09-30 00:00:00|Source|count|19089222|-19.4%|Normal|2022|202209|20220930
2022-09-30 00:00:00|2022-09-30 00:00:00|Source|count|29014921|-2.47%|Normal|2022|202209|20220930
2022-09-30 00:00:00|2022-09-30 00:00:00|Source|count|148770415|-0.14%|Normal|2022|202209|20220930
```

i've tried using `cat output.csv | grep -v -i "No " | sed 's/\.//g' > output3.csv` But it will convert all columns that have "." .

So how to converting "." to blankspace in 5th column without affect on 6th column with still csv format output?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091138/regex-replace-on-specific-column-with-sed-awk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074171/awk-edit-only-1-column-with-regex

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to do this in `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" } { gsub("[.]","",$5) } 1' file
```

But if you insist on using `sed`:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 's/^\(\([^|]*|\)\{4\}[^|]*\)\./\1/' -e 'ta' file
```

Comment: can i ask you to detailing the script? i dont understand at :
- BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" } 
- "1" at the end

Thank you

Comment: @cankcimen `FS=OFS="|"` sets both input and output field separators to `|`. `1` at the end prints the `$0`.

Comment: Ah i see, thank you. Can i ask 1 more thing, where can i learn more about this "sed" and "awk" function?

Comment: @cankcimenc Search for "GNU Awk User's Guide" and "GNU sed manual"

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and shell):

```
sed 'y/|/\n/;s/.*/echo "&"|sed "5s#\\.##g"/e;y/\n/|/' file
```

In essence, turn each line into a file and run a second invocation of sed where each address represents a column in the original line.

Translate `|`'s to newlines.

Write a mini sed invocation each time the pattern space is presented, that removes all `.`'s from the 5th line (each line in the invocation represents a column in the original line).

Translate newlines back to `|`'s.